# Aligning a div with 2 divs inside it in Center

Tags: html, css

[image: http://puu.sh/gXHVO/f5f2addb9b.png (link to image)]

Currently im trying to get 2 divs  to align in center, but not quite sure how to do it. They go to the Left side by default.

I had margin-left:14 % and it would align it somewhat in the center, but when you re-sized the window it would look weird because it aligned to the right side.

tried with with with marign-left/right:auto, but no result.

html

```
<div id="panels">

<div id="panel-left">           
</div>

<div id="panel-right">  
</div>
```

css

```html
#panels{
padding-top:15px;
margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#panel-left{
width:32%;
min-width:209px;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:white;
float:left;
padding-left:25px;
height:473px;
}

#panel-right{
width:32%;
min-width:209px;
height:473px;
background-color:white;
float:left;
padding-left:25px;
}
```

Comment: In your html above you're not closing <div id="panels"> - is this causing the problem?

Comment: well, the right and left panel are inside the #panels. it's closed after them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
#panels{
    padding-top:15px;
    text-align:center;
    display: block;
}

#panel-left{
    width:32%;
    min-width:209px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:black;
    height:473px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#panel-right{
    width:32%;
    min-width:209px;
    height:473px;
    background-color:orange;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/mpw2r8h2/6/)**

Comment: thanks, works somehow. Only problem is that it makes a slight gap between the 2 divs (1-2px) and looks weird

Comment: Yes...do not separate the two divs (backspace/enter) like my demo. don´t give space between them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this style, I have used the box sizing css property to take care of the inherent 1px space that occurs during inline styling.

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/svaidhyanath/mrxd8yj7/)**

Of course there was an un-closed div element in your initial code which is fixed now.

So the CSS looks like,

```
#panels {
    padding-top:15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: cyan;
    width:50%; /* u need this */
    height:500px;
}
#panel-left {
    width:50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
   /* min-width:209px;   By doing this you are pretty much giving the width to be 100 % */
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:gray;
    float:left;
    padding-left:25px;
    height:473px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#panel-right {
    width:50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    /*min-width:209px;*/
    height:473px;
    background-color:white;
    float:left;
    padding-left:25px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Code snippet::

```css
#panels {
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: cyan;
  width: 50%;
  /* u need this */
  height: 500px;
}
#panel-left {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* min-width:209px;   By doing this you are pretty much giving the width to be 100 % */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
  height: 473px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#panel-right {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*min-width:209px;*/
  height: 473px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="panels">
  <div id="panel-left">left</div>
  <div id="panel-right">right</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. **Happy Coding :)**